# Charisma style dashboard panel in the admin section of a Laravel 4 site?

Tags: php, laravel, dashboard, laravel-4, charisma

Forgive me for being a beginner in php and I hope my question is not too vague or incomplete.  I'm learning and I am really enjoying Laravel 4.  Unfortunately, with it being so new, there are not many tutorials and questions out there other than general get up and go type stuff.

I saw the Charisma bundle for L3 and I would love to implement a dashboard like this in to my admin panel but I'm a bit confused.  I don't think Charisma is available for L4 yet but does anyone know a tutorial that covers this?  Or any info on how this would be structured would be greatly appreciated. I'd really like to buy a dashboard html theme and port it to my Laravel 4 site as my dashboard. Something like this {http://themeforest.net/item/pannonia-fully-responsive-admin-template/4360373}

I have downloaded and messed around with the Laravel Bootstrap starter site on github as well as viewed and completed some tutorials on how to make a site with a backend here { http://www.codeforest.net/laravel4-simple-website-with-backend-1}.  So I'm not too concerned with the login / auth part of the admin. Just a little confused on where to start as far as making the dashboard my main admin section and how to make it function inside laravel 4 calling the different pieces in the dashboard.

Again, any help or tips would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by better understanding the [blade template system](http://laravel.com/docs/templates) built in to laravel 4.  It's extremely fast and easy to create views with the .blade.php extension and include them in to your code.